# Robopurging expired files

Tags: powershell

This script uses robocopy purge with list command to out what would be purged it then parses that log file and checks each file and only deletes files older than 7 days. Is there way it could be simplified to maybe use less log files in the process?

```
$Log = "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\list.txt"
$extrafile = "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\extrafile.txt"
$extradir = "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\extradir.txt"
$extraparsed = "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\extraparsed.txt"
$purged = "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\purged.txt"
$now = Get-Date
$days = "7"
$Lastwrite = $now.AddDays(-$days)
$datetime = get-date -f MM-dd-yy-hhmmtt

If (Test-Path "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\list.txt"){
        Remove-Item "D:\IT\Backups\Logs\list.txt"
}

robocopy "\\10.10.10.9\tcart" "\\192.168.1.44\tcartbkup" /e /Purge /R:1 /W:1 /l /TEE /FP /LOG:"D:\IT\Backups\Logs\list.txt" /MT:16 

If (Test-Path $extradir){
        Remove-Item $extradir
}

If (Test-Path $extrafile){
        Remove-Item $extrafile
}

If (Test-Path $extraparsed){
        Remove-Item $extraparsed
}
If (Test-Path $purged){
        rename-item $purged -newname ("purged-" + $datetime + ".txt")
}

Get-Content $Log | Select-String "EXTRA File" | Out-File $extrafile -Width 5000
Get-Content $Log | Select-String "EXTRA Dir" | Out-File $extradir -Width 5000

cat $extradir | %{$_.Substring(28)} | Out-File $extraparsed
cat $extrafile | %{$_.Substring(38)} | Out-File $extraparsed -Append

$files = Get-Content $extraparsed | Select-String "\\" | ForEach-Object {(Get-Item "$_")} | Where {ForEach-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -le "$Lastwrite")}}

foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        if ($File -ne $NULL)
            {
             Write-Host "Deleting File $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
             Write-Output "Deleting File $File" | Out-File $purged -Append
             Remove-Item $file.FullName -Recurse | Out-Null
             }
             else
             {
             Write-Host "No More files to delete" -ForegroundColor "Green"
             Write-Output "No More files to delete" | Out-File $purged -Append
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

To reduce the amount of log files I would keep things in memory:

```
$Log = "C:\scripts\list.txt"
$purged = "C:\scripts\purged.txt"
$now = Get-Date
$days = "7"
$Lastwrite = $now.AddDays(-$days)
$datetime = get-date -f MM-dd-yy-hhmmtt

#Robocopy will automatically overwrite the log file unless you specifiy /log+:
robocopy "c:\downloads" "c:\downloads1" /e /Purge /R:1 /W:1 /l /TEE /FP /LOG:"$log" /MT:16 

#Save purged log
rename-item $purged ($purged -replace('.txt', "_$datetime.txt"))

Get-Content $Log | foreach {

    #Split columns by tab
    $fileType =  ( $_ -split("`t") )[1]
    $filePath =  ( $_ -split("`t") )[2]


    if ( ($fileType -like "*Extra File*") -or ($fileType -like "*Extra Dir*") ){
        if ( (Get-Item $filePath).LastWriteTime -le $Lastwrite){
            "Deleting File: $filePath" | Out-File $purged -Append
            remove-item $filePath -WhatIf -Recurse
        }
    }

}
```